# Boot error msg: [FAILED] and [DEPEND]

Tags: linux, fedora, systemd

I have a error during boot system a few miliseconds. The error msg:

```
[FAILED]: Failed to start Setup Virtual Console.
[DEPEND]: Dependency failed for dracut ask for additional cmdline parameters.
```

When I login system, verify this service systemd-vconsole-setup and work fine:

```
systemd-vconsole-setup.service - Setup Virtual Console
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-vconsole-setup.service; static)
     Active: active (exited) since Sun 2021-05-23 13:55:58 -03; 56min ago
       Docs: man:systemd-vconsole-setup.service(8)
             man:vconsole.conf(5)
    Process: 538 ExecStart=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-vconsole-setup (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 538 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 62ms
```

I search logs boot and I found that:

```
may 23 16:06:03 fedora systemd-vconsole-setup[248]: loadkeys: Unable to open file: la-latin1: No such file or directory
may 23 16:06:05 fedora systemd[1]: Starting Setup Virtual Console...
may 23 16:06:05 fedora systemd-vconsole-setup[490]: loadkeys: Unable to open file: la-latin1: No such file or directory
may 23 16:06:05 fedora systemd-vconsole-setup[487]: /usr/bin/loadkeys failed with exit status 1.
may 23 16:06:05 fedora systemd-vconsole-setup[487]: KD_FONT_OP_GET failed while trying to get the font metadata: Invalid argument
may 23 16:06:05 fedora systemd-vconsole-setup[487]: Fonts will not be copied to remaining consoles
may 23 16:06:05 fedora systemd[1]: systemd-vconsole-setup.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
may 23 16:06:05 fedora systemd[1]: systemd-vconsole-setup.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
may 23 16:06:05 fedora systemd[1]: Failed to start Setup Virtual Console.
may 23 19:06:06 fedora systemd[1]: Finished Setup Virtual Console.
```

This line:
`Unable to open file: la-latin1: No such file or directory`

I dont not why appears, my config `localectl` is:

```
   System Locale: LANG=es_ES.UTF-8
       VC Keymap: es
      X11 Layout: latam,us
     X11 Variant: ,colemak_dh
```

i was changing `la-latin` to `es`, because of service `systemd-vconsole-setup` was failed.

I dont know appear a few seconds, during boot:  `Failed to start Setup Virtual Console.`

Some can help me ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What's the output of `journalctl -b | grep -i dracut`?

Comment: i solved that error, i did update package and these error not appear more.

Answer (score 1):

Just I did update package and these error not appear more and the kernel was update:

`Linux rodrigo-linux 5.11.21-300.fc34.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri May 14 17:43:38 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

To:

`Linux linux 5.12.9-300.fc34.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jun 3 13:51:40 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`